# running jar file with dependencies : java could not find or load the main class OSMImportTool

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to run a jar file from a Windows command prompt. From what i can see all the code and dependencies are there. The code given to run this is :

> java -Xms1280m -Xmx1280m -cp
>   "target/osm-0.2.2-neo4j-3.5.1.jar:target/dependency/*"
>   org.neo4j.gis.osm.OSMImportTool --skip-duplicate-nodes --delete --into
>   target/databases/map2 samples/map2.osm.bz2

The error returned is:

> java could not find or load the main class
>   org.neo4j.gis.osm.OSMImportTool.

Have tried playing around with the path but no luck. Any suggestions how to make this work would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the class:  org.neo4j.gis.osm.OSMImportTool  located? Is it in the correct folder: path to the class file == package name

Comment: The path to the class file is:

...target/dependency/org/neo4j/gis/osm/OSMImportTool.class

Comment: Windows uses a ; as a path separator.  Is the target folder in the directory where the java command is issued?

Comment: I've changed directories to to folder containing the target folder and run the java there and also have tried the full path. 

Sorry I gave you the wrong path above. The file is located at: ...target/classes/org/neo4j/gis/osm/OSMImportTool.class

I'll try the ; as a separator and see what happens

Comment: I've tried the ; as a separator still not working- cheers

Comment: Yeap  Thanks, working with replacing the : with a ;  - well got a wee bit further - now running into other issues in the jar itself, but at least it found it!

Answer (score 0):

java -Xms1280m -Xmx1280m -cp "target/osm-0.2.2-neo4j-3.5.1.jar;target/dependency/*" org.neo4j.gis.osm.OSMImportTool --skip-duplicate-nodes --delete --into target/databases/map2 samples/map2.osm.bz2

replaced the colon with a semi colon

Comment: Solved the problem